# What kind of topological structures are there?

Tags: topology

This is a more open question about the best practices for topology. I couldn't find much about it in tutorials. I want to know what kind of topological patterns are used depending on the object that is being represented. I found this topology online where you have six diamond shaped quads ordered in a hexagon. Are there more patterns like this and what are best practices for topological patterns depending on the material you want to represent?
 [image: This is a screenshot of a model by Ustavshiyangel https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/bouquet-irises-vase-3d-model/738527]

Comment: Consider that topology *only* matters if you want to deform the mesh.

Answer (score 2):

Your example shows geometry with *Subdivision Surface algorithm* on top.

- *Subdivision Surface* works with quads, and when they're not there, it transforms the geometry.
- Your image shows *Subdivison Surface* applied on top of triangles.

---

[image]

Comment: Further reading (for the sake): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catmull%E2%80%93Clark_subdivision_surface